# Mix vertex and curveVertex in a shape?

Tags: p5.js, shapes

I am trying to create a shape with both straight lines and curved parts. I want all points to connect and then to fill the interior with a color. I cannot seem to locate this information or a way to do it in a single shape. Is there a way to do this? For example a rectangle with an inverted curve on each end? I can do it with arcs and lines like the below code but I have to think there is an easier way using beginShape somehow or something similar? Also even using the lines and arcs, I am not sure how to fill it.

```
  arc(200, 200, 150, 150, radians(0), radians(90), OPEN);

  arc(200, 200, 50, 50, radians(0), radians(90), OPEN);
  
  let x1 = 200 + Math.cos(radians(0)) * 25;
  let y1 = 200 + Math.sin(radians(0)) * 25;
  
  let x2 = 200 + Math.cos(radians(90)) * 25;
  let y2 = 200 + Math.sin(radians(90)) * 25;
  
  let x3 = 200 + Math.cos(radians(0)) * 75;
  let y3 = 200 + Math.sin(radians(0)) * 75;
  
  let x4 = 200 + Math.cos(radians(90)) * 75;
  let y4 = 200 + Math.sin(radians(90)) * 75;
  
  line(x1, y1, x3, y3)
  line(x2, y2, x4, y4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should answer part of your question experimentally. As you can see by playing with the sketch below, if there is a single `curveVertex()` in the shape all of the vertices created with `vertex()` will also be treated as `curveVertex()` type vertices.

I think you should be able to achieve your goal with [`bezierVertex()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/bezierVertex).

```js
const InteractionThreshold = 5;
const SqInteractionThreshold = InteractionThreshold * InteractionThreshold;

function lineEditor(p) {
  let controlPoints = [{
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      type: 'vertex'
    },
    {
      x: 250,
      y: 250,
      type: 'vertex'
    },
  ];

  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(300, 300);
    p.rectMode(p.RADIUS);
    p.ellipseMode(p.RADIUS);
    p.noFill();
    p.noLoop();
  };

  p.draw = () => {
    p.background(200);

    p.beginShape();
    for (let i = 0; i < controlPoints.length; i++) {
      let pt = controlPoints[i];
      switch (pt.type) {
        case 'vertex':
          p.vertex(pt.x, pt.y);
          break;
        case 'curve':
          p.curveVertex(pt.x, pt.y);
          break;
      }
    }
    p.endShape();

    p.push();
    p.stroke('green');
    p.drawingContext.setLineDash([5, 15]);
    p.beginShape();
    for (let i = 0; i < controlPoints.length; i++) {
      let pt = controlPoints[i];
      p.vertex(pt.x, pt.y);
    }
    p.endShape();
    p.drawingContext.setLineDash([]);
    p.pop();

    p.push();
    p.fill("red");
    p.noStroke();
    for (let i = 0; i < controlPoints.length; i++) {
      let pt = controlPoints[i];
      switch (pt.type) {
        case 'curve':
          p.circle(pt.x, pt.y, 4);
          break;
        case 'vertex':
          p.push();
          p.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
          p.rotate(p.PI / 4);
          p.square(0, 0, 4);
          p.pop();
          break;
      }
    }
    p.pop();
  };

  let dragging;

  p.mousePressed = function() {
    // is the mouse over a point
    let closest = getClosest(p.mouseX, p.mouseY);

    if (closest && closest.sqdist < SqInteractionThreshold) {
      dragging = closest.ix;
    }
  };

  p.mouseReleased = function() {
    dragging = undefined;
  };

  p.mouseDragged = function() {
    if (dragging !== undefined) {
      controlPoints[dragging].x = p.constrain(p.mouseX, 0, p.width);
      controlPoints[dragging].y = p.constrain(p.mouseY, 0, p.height);
      p.redraw();
    }
  };

  p.mouseClicked = function() {
    if (p.keyIsDown(p.SHIFT)) {
      // is the mouse over a point
      let closest = getClosest(p.mouseX, p.mouseY);

      if (closest && closest.sqdist < SqInteractionThreshold) {
        let pt = controlPoints[closest.ix];
        switch (pt.type) {
          case 'vertex':
            pt.type = 'curve';
            break;
          case 'curve':
            pt.type = 'vertex';
            break;
        }
        p.redraw();
      }
    }
  }

  p.doubleClicked = function() {
    if (p.keyIsDown(p.SHIFT)) {
      if (controlPoints.length > 2) {
        // delete
        let closest = getClosest(p.mouseX, p.mouseY);

        if (closest && closest.sqdist < SqInteractionThreshold) {
          controlPoints.splice(closest.ix, 1);
          p.redraw();
        }
      }
    } else {
      // insert
      let closest = getClosestSegment(p.mouseX, p.mouseY);

      if (closest.error < InteractionThreshold) {
        controlPoints.splice(closest.end, 0, {
          x: p.mouseX,
          y: p.mouseY,
          type: 'vertex'
        });
        p.redraw();
      }
    }
  };

  function getClosest(x, y) {
    let closest;
    for (let i = 0; i < controlPoints.length; i++) {
      let dx = x - controlPoints[i].x;
      let dy = y - controlPoints[i].y;
      let sqdist = dx * dx + dy * dy;
      if (!closest || sqdist < closest.sqdist) {
        closest = {
          sqdist,
          ix: i
        };
      }
    }

    return closest;
  }


  function getClosestSegment(x, y) {
    let closest;
    for (let i = 0; i < controlPoints.length - 1; i++) {
      let start = controlPoints[i];
      let end = controlPoints[i + 1];
      let angle = p.atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x);
      let len = p.dist(start.x, start.y, end.x, end.y);
      // convert [mouseX, mouseY] to a position relative to start
      let vec = p.createVector(x - start.x, y - start.y);
      vec = p.createVector(
        p.cos(angle) * vec.x + p.sin(angle) * vec.y, -p.sin(angle) * vec.x + p.cos(angle) * vec.y,
      );
      let error;
      if (vec.x < 0) {
        error = p.dist(0, 0, vec.x, vec.y);
      } else if (vec.x > len) {
        error = p.dist(len, 0, vec.x, vec.y);
      } else {
        // There is no X error, only consider the Y
        error = p.abs(vec.y);
      }

      if (!closest || error < closest.error) {
        closest = {
          error,
          start: i,
          end: i + 1
        };
      }
    }

    return closest;
  }
}

let lineEditorSketch = new p5(lineEditor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```